# How to calculate retirement year of staff

Tags: python, html, django

I am building HR app using python with Django framework, I am having issue to calculation  retirement year of an employee, for example if an employee enters his/her date of birth let the system calculate his/her retirement year or how many years remaining to retire. staff retire at 60 years

Am getting this error:

```
TypeError at /staffprofile/profile_entry/
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8080/staffprofile/profile_entry/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime'
Exception Location: /home/bakceesay/djangoapps/NAO/venv/src/staffprofile/views.py in profile_entry, line 57
```

this is my code in views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect # HttpResponse allows the get_absolute_url to work ## and HttpresponseRedirect redirects page after a process
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from django.contrib import messages
from datetime import datetime,  timedelta


def profile_entry(request):
        title = 'ADD YOUR PROFILE INFORMATION'
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) 
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            date_of_birth = instance.date_of_birth

            age_days = (datetime.now().date() - date_of_birth)
            age = (age_days/365)


            rem_yrs = (60 - int(age))

            instance.date_of_retirement = rem_yrs
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved')
            return redirect('/profile/profile_detail')
        context = {
            "title": title,
            "form": form,
         }
        return render(request, "profile_entry.html",context)
```

models.py

```
[address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
email_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
date_of_hire = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
date_of_termination = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
date_of_retirement = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)][1]
```

Comment: Don't try doing this yourself, there are many quirks with dates that you won't account for. There are many duplicates to do with adding years to a date.

Comment: am not jetting it can you be more specific

Comment: Just add 60 years to the date of birth

Comment: Am new to django, can you please help on how to add 60 years to date field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely starting this out right by getting a datetime object for both the current day and their birthday. Create the retirement object by the following:

```
retirement = date_of_birth.replace(year=date_of_birth.year+60)
```

And then get the retirement year by getting the property

```
retirement.year
```

Finally, get the years remaining by

```
retirement.year-datetime.now().date().year
```

I wouldn't take the difference in days and divide by 365 because of leap years. This method will, however, round up the current age of the person and no fractions of a year will exist. If you want more precision, I would add in months rather than fractions of a year. Just use the .month attribute of datetime if you want this.

Answer (score 0):

While you was told in comments that it's not a best way to continue, I'll try to answer this question -

> How to add 60 years to date field?

you can use [relative delta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html#module-dateutil.relativedelta) (to consider leap years day diff):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
...
ret_age = instance.date_of_birth + relativedelta(years=60)
ret_days = ret_age.days
```

Also, make sure you know about [tz aware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) datetime.